# Direct Initialization of member in class definition

Tags: c++, initialization

Why can't we use direct initialization within a class definition? For example, we can use a `int z = 5;` statement, but can't use `int y(10);` within the class definition below.

```
class Myclass {      
  int y(); // "error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
  int z=5;
};
```

Comment: Are you initializing a member variable named `y`, or declaring a member function `y` that takes no arguments and returns `int`?

Comment: What's the difference between the *function* declaration `int y();` and the *variable* definition `int y();`? If you can't tell, then how would the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization):

> Non-static data members may be initialized in **one of two ways**:
>
> 1. In the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) of the constructor.
>
> ```
> struct S
> {
>     int n;
>     std::string s;
>     S() : n(7) {} // direct-initializes n, default-initializes s
> };
> ```
>
> 2. Through a *default member initializer*, which is a **brace or equals [initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)** included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>
> ```
> struct S
> {
>     int n = 7;
>     std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};
>     S() {} // default member initializer will copy-initialize n, list-initialize s
> };
> ```

So, you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

`int y{10};`

This will invoke [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) in this case:

> `T object { arg };`   (2)     (since C++11)
>
> Direct initialization is performed in the following situations:
> ...
> 2) initialization of an object of non-class type with a single brace-enclosed initializer (note: for class types and other uses of braced-init-list, see [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) (since C++11)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) here as @Remy Lebeau already mentioned. But you can also use the zero initialization described in the link: `int y{};`